# Not able to connect to PostgreSQL via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, dbconnection, node-postgres

Below is the connection details

```
exports.DB_NAME                         = "postgres";
exports.DB_USERNAME                     = "abcd";
exports.DB_PASSWORD                     = "abcd1234";
exports.DB_HOST                         = "abcd.cvg87ikjlfjt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
exports.DB_PORT                         = "5432";
exports.DB_SCHEMA                       = "ABCD";
```

And this is how my NodeJS code looks like

```
var config = {
  user: CONSTANT.DB_USERNAME,
  database: CONSTANT.DB_SCHEMA,
  host: CONSTANT.DB_HOST,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  port: CONSTANT.DB_PORT
};
console.log("config : "+JSON.stringify(config));
var pool = new pg.Pool(config);
```

It's failing when I pass the config object to Pool constructor.
It gives me the below error

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:5432
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

Searched through all the forums and everyone has made a mistake in the hostname. But that's not the case here.
Not sure why am getting this error.
My NodeJS version is 4.4.2 and PostgreSQL version is 9.5.2

Any help/suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `console.log("config : "...` show? Does it print correct JSON with credentials?

Comment: Yes, it does. It prints the data as expected.

Comment: Try adding the error handler, and see if you are getting an error there: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool#error

Comment: I added the below block after passing config to Pool constructor
`
pool.on('error', function(error, client) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
`
However I don't think this particular block itself will be executed because pool object itself is not getting create.
Hope am making sense here?

Comment: Hi @Maga, did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe is DB_PORT is a number and you are declaring with a String, Can you try it this?

```
exports.DB_PORT = 5432;
```